# Feign : Basic Auth issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, feign, openfeign

I want to call a microservice from an other using a Basic Auth.

I have a Feign Client configured as follow :

```
package com.example.test.rest;

import com.example.test.config.FeignClientConfiguration;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@FeignClient(name = "client-test", url = "localhost:8080", configuration = FeignClientConfiguration.class)
public interface TestProxy {

  @GetMapping (value = "/test")
  @ResponseBody
  String getTest();
}
```

and the feign configuration with a custom credential provider to retrieve user and password:

```
@Configuration
public class FeignClientConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  private CustomCredentialsProvider customCredentialsProvider;

  @Bean
  public BasicAuthRequestInterceptor basicAuthRequestInterceptor() {
    Credentials credentials = customCredentialsProvider.getCredentials();
    return new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor(credentials.getUser(), credentials.getPassword());
  }
}
```

Everything is working fine until I change the credentials. Then the BasicAuthInterceptor does not have the new credentials. Is it possible to refresh it at runtime ?

My environment : java 17, springboot 3, openfeign 4,

Thanks !